# Map values [in Col A] that share a common value [in Col B], and place match into Col C

Tags: python, excel, string-matching, openrefine

I am hoping to map 'patent (source)' [Col A] to 'patent drain' [Col C] when both rows share the same [CPC] value in Col B. An example would be

[image]

The result would look like this

[image]

Appreciate your help to achieve this outcome using either XLS, Python or Open Refine (am a novice/beginner with the last two but anxious to deepen my skills in them)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use a formula like: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,INDEX((B:B=B2)*(ROW(B:B)<>ROW()),),0))` in `C2` and depending on how much data you have I would advise to use range references instead of whole columns. Python is also a possibility, however I would focus on either one, not on both.

Comment: That solution works very nicely - thank you!